# Using Post Method in my code

Tags: php, html

Can you help me with this?

How can i pass the info that I selected from Index.php to productinfo.php ?
My friend told me that I should use "post method" but i don't know how to 
apply it to my code...

here is my code

```
index.php:

<?php require_once('Connections/localhost.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

$theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$maxRows_showproduct = 6;
$pageNum_showproduct = 0;
if (isset($_GET['pageNum_showproduct'])) {
  $pageNum_showproduct = $_GET['pageNum_showproduct'];
}
$startRow_showproduct = $pageNum_showproduct * $maxRows_showproduct;

mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
$query_showproduct = "SELECT * FROM product";
$query_limit_showproduct = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_showproduct,  $startRow_showproduct, $maxRows_showproduct);
$showproduct = mysql_query($query_limit_showproduct, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
$row_showproduct = mysql_fetch_assoc($showproduct);

if (isset($_GET['totalRows_showproduct'])) {
  $totalRows_showproduct = $_GET['totalRows_showproduct'];
} else {
  $all_showproduct = mysql_query($query_showproduct);
  $totalRows_showproduct = mysql_num_rows($all_showproduct);
}
$totalPages_showproduct =     ceil($totalRows_showproduct/$maxRows_showproduct)-1;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Home</title>
<link href="css/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="header"></div>
     <!-- *************************** MENU -->
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>  
            <li><a href="signup.php">Signup</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- *************************** CATEGORY -->
    <div id="category"><ul>
            <li><a href="computers.php"><img src="images/menudesktop.png" width="333" height="100" border="0"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="laptops.php"><img src="images/menulaptop.png" width="333" height="100" alt=""/></a></li>
            <li><a href="mobiles.php"><img src="images/menumobile.png" width="333" height="100" alt=""/></a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>       
    <!-- *************************** BRAND -->     
    <div id="brand">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Intel</a></li>  
            <li><a href="#">Lenovo</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Samsung</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dell</a></li>   
            <li><a href="#">Cherry Mobile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Apple</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>   
    <form id="mainbodyform" name="mainbodyform" method="post"     action="productinfo.php">
    <!-- *************************** MAINBODY --> 

    <div id="mainbody">

        <!-- *************************** PRODUCT CONTAINER -->

      <?php do { ?>
        <div id="productcontainer">
          <div id="imgbox"></div>
          <div id="txtbox">
            <table width="250" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row_showproduct['name']; ?></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row_showproduct['brand']; ?></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row_showproduct['category']; ?></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>₱<?php echo $row_showproduct['price']; ?></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Buy Now!" /></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
          <?php } while ($row_showproduct = mysql_fetch_assoc($showproduct)); ?>
    </div>
    </form>
  <!-- *************************** FOOTER -->
  <div id="footer"><p>Runts & Giants</p></div>   

</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($showproduct);
?>
```

And This is my productinfo.php

```
<?php @session_start(); ?>
<?php require_once('Connections/localhost.php'); ?>
<?php
$_SESSION['Index.php']=3;
?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
$query_productinfo = "SELECT * FROM product";
$productinfo = mysql_query($query_productinfo, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
$row_productinfo = mysql_fetch_assoc($productinfo);
$totalRows_productinfo = mysql_num_rows($productinfo);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>layout</title>
<link href="css/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/productinfostyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="header"></div>
     <!-- *************************** MENU -->
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Order</a></li>  
            <li><a href="#">Cart</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- *************************** CATEGORY -->
    <div id="category"><ul>
            <li><a href="computers.php"><img src="images/menudesktop.png" width="333" height="100" border="0"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="laptops.php"><img src="images/menulaptop.png" width="333" height="100" alt=""/></a></li>
            <li><a href="mobiles.php"><img src="images/menumobile.png" width="333" height="100" alt=""/></a></li>
        </ul>
  </div>       
  <!-- *************************** BRAND -->     
    <div id="brand">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Intel</a></li>  
            <li><a href="#">Lenovo</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Samsung</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dell</a></li>   
            <li><a href="#">Cherry Mobile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Apple</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>   
  <!-- *************************** MAINBODY --> 
    <div id="mainbody">
        <form id="productform" name="productform.php" method="">
          <div id="itemimg">1</div>
            <div id="itemdesc"><br />
              <br />
              <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                  <td width="301"><table width="300" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td><?php echo $row_productinfo['name']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><?php echo $row_productinfo['brand']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><?php echo $row_productinfo['category']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><?php echo $row_productinfo['price']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Add to Cart" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table></td>
                  <td width="299"><?php echo $row_productinfo['description']; ?></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>


        </form>
  </div>
  <!-- *************************** FOOTER -->
    <div id="footer"><p>Runts & Giants</p></div>   

</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($productinfo);
?>
```

Thanks...

Comment: How can i pass the info that* I selected from Index.php to productinfo.php ? My friend told me that I should use "post method" but i don't know how to apply it to my code...

Answer (score 1):

> you need to add from as below in index.php when this form submit it will redirect to product page and you will get your value

```
<form id="productform" name="productform.php" action="productform.php" method="post">
          <div id="itemimg">1</div>
            <div id="itemdesc"><br />
              <br />
              <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                  <td width="301"><table width="300" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td><?php echo $row_productinfo['name']; ?>
                      <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row_productinfo['name']; ?>" name="product_name"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><?php echo $row_productinfo['brand']; ?>
                      <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row_productinfo['brand']; ?>" name="product_brand">
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><?php echo $row_productinfo['category']; ?>
                      <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row_productinfo['category']; ?>" name="product_category">
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><?php echo $row_productinfo['price']; ?>
                      <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row_productinfo['price']; ?>" name="product_price">
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Add to Cart" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table></td>
                  <td width="299"><?php echo $row_productinfo['description']; ?></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>


        </form>
```

> and in productinfo.php you need to add

```
    <?php  if(isset($_POST['submit'])):
        echo $name=$_POST['product_name'];
        echo $brand=$_POST['product_brand'];
       echo  $category=$_POST['product_category'];
       echo  $price=$_POST['product_price'];
endif;
        ?>
```

> use this variable where you need on this page

Comment: Sir. I tried your code... 

but i get this error... 



    "( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\wamp\www\ecommFinale\productinfo.php on line 137."

What is causing this?.

Comment: ie due to end the if condition in if(isset($_POST['submit'])):   we need to add endif; after echo  $price=$_POST['product_price'];

Comment: i have added endif; on above code. then it work for you

Comment: Hi... when i tried to put your code in mine... (index.php) i got this error... 
( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: row_productinfo in C:\wamp\www\ecommFinale\Index.php on line 120

Comment: that was the  variable name you can replave $row_procutinfo['name'] by $row_showproduct['name']; similarly other variable.

Comment: Hi... i tried your code this way.... " <?php  if(isset($_POST['submit'])): echo $price=$_POST['price']; endif; ?> " but its displaying different product from what i selected in index.php...

Comment: check the value that you selected and the value assign to hidden field by inspecting in browser. if different value is assigned the you must correct some other code too. and you can also select option inside the <form></form>

Comment: do i have to use hidden field?

Comment: if we like to hide the field from user but need to pass some value from form then we need to use hidden field. if you like to use text field and donen't need to show to user then you can use hidden field other wise it is not necessory

Answer (score 0):

**Your form doesn't have any fields.**

1) Do these changes in your index.php:

```
      <tr>
        <td><input name="name" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_showproduct['name']; ?>" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input name="brand" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_showproduct['brand']; ?>" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input name="category" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_showproduct['category']; ?>" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input name="price" type="text" value="<?php echo $row_showproduct['price']; ?>" /></td>
      </tr>
```

2) Make sure productinfo.php do something with the data. Use: print_r($_POST) to check post data.

> Don't use mysql_* functions. They are already deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and removed in PHP 7. Insead use: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php
>
> Learn how to handle a form: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/form-handler/

Comment: Sir. Sorry for this question. 
what should i do with the "mysql_* functions"? 

and how can i use print_r($_POST) ? 

i already do some searching but i still can't get the full understanding on it...

Answer (score 0):

Yes your friend told is right you can pass a data  from one page to another page using post.

There are Four way to you can pass a data from one page to another page.

**1.Using Form**

You need to feel the data in the form and on submit the form you redirect to another page(defined in action attribute of form) and you retrieve the data in rdirected page

let's one example
**index.php**

```
<form action="production.php" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="txt_name">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="product">
</form>
```

**production.php**

```
<?php
// on submit button is clicked
if(isset($_POST['product'])){
   if(isset($_POST['txt_name']) && $_POST['txt_name'] != ""){
     $name = $_POST['txt_name'];
    }

}
?>
```

above code is check submit button is clicked if clicked than vale of input text is set,if set than it's not a blank than retrieve name

here we use `$_POST` coz method of form is set **"post"** default method is **"get"**.if you didn't defined any method than default method get is set.so you can retrieve data using `$_GET`

You can also retrieve data no matter which method is set in form method attribute,using `$_REQUEST`

**2.Using Anchor**

**3.Using Session**

**4.Using Cookie**

Answer (score -2):

First, you have to create some fields and set it val via javascript when user select a row in table. After this, you get the infos in productinfo.php via $_POST['name_of_field_in_index.php']

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how to make/create codes... I just build those codes above in dreamweaver...

Comment: is there any idea other than js ?